# Android - Show full screen notification when screen is unlocked

Tags: android, notifications, unlock

I want to show the full-screen notification when I receive an FCM in the background. I am assigning a pending indent to `.setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenIntent, true)` in my notification builder. This is working as expected when the screen is locked.

But when the screen is unlocked it just shows as any other normal notification. How can I let the notification be full screen even when the screen is unlocked?